# How can I use Provider to provide a bloc to a PageView() without the child resubscribing everytime I switch page?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-provider

I am using Provider to provide my bloc to a widget called TheGroupPage via a static create method

```
  static Widget create(BuildContext context, GroupModel group) {
    final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context);
    return Provider(
      create: (_) => GroupMembersBloc(database, group),
      child: TheGroupPage(group),
      dispose: (BuildContext context, GroupMembersBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
    );
  }
```

That widget has a PageView() with 3 pages

```
  PageView(children: [
    TheGroupNotificationsView(),
    TheGroupMembersView(group),
    TheGroupSettingsView(group),
  ])
```

The group members view looks for the GroupMembersBloc

```
GroupMembersBloc bloc = Provider.of<GroupMembersBloc>(context);
```

I also tried to put listen to false but this did not work. And I want the widget to listen for any changes. The page uses that bloc's stream to draw a list of group members

```
class GroupMembersBloc{

  StreamController<List<UserModel>> _controller = StreamController<List<UserModel>>();
  Stream<List<UserModel>> get stream => _controller.stream;

  GroupMembersBloc(DatabaseService database, GroupModel group)
  {
   _controller.addStream(database.groupMembersStream(group));
  }

  void dispose(){
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

The problem is when I switch page inside the PageView() I get an error on the page after the first time it has been shown. The error says `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` how can I solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up moving the StreamBuilder to the parent widget above the PageView() which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because stream controllers allow only 1 Subscription (or 1 listener) , you could use the [`StreamController<List<UserModel>>.broadcast()][1]` constructor instead of StreamController>().

Comment: Yes but I only have 1 page that listens to the stream. So why make it a broadcast stream? I would have multiple unnecessary listeners. Isn't there a way to stop listening when the page is being switched withing the PageView()?